# bash: ssh-host-config: command not found

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, openssh

Does anyone have ANY ideas what could be causing this.

I am on win 7. I have successfully setup everything using this tutorial:

http://www.kgx.net.nz/2010/03/cygwin-sshd-and-windows-7/

I am up to this command:

ssh-host-config

..but I receive the error in the title. I have searched google and many other places. I cannot find one instance of somebody having this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure openssh (which presumably contains the command ssh-host-config) is actually installed. Check your PATH, and make sure it contains the directory containing that command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://allthingsmarked.com/2006/08/17/how-to-set-up-a-windows-ssh-server-for-vnc-tunneling/

You probably forgot to check the openssh.  I forgot this when downloading to a folder using the setup.

Comment: The CygWin installation does not have to be started again. It is possible to install individual CygWin packages using cyg-get. Chocolatey could be used to install cyg-get by issuing `cinst cyg-get` and subsequently `cyg-get openssh`

Comment: Thanks. Also in the cygwin setup package, I had to install both the /bin and /src ssh package. Thanks to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwYSvvGaiWU

Answer (score 0):

Don't download all the packages at once I did this and thought everything was fine until I got the same error. Just download the openssh package and make sure the X is in the box, it a big file so could take a while.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen if you need to add your cygwin\bin path to your windows path. If you add it to your Windows path, you might be all set. I would add it at the end so that you don't potentially mess up other Windows commands.

Make sure to close all shell and Bash windows before trying again. Otherwise the change won't take effect.