# cygwin net start sshd command not found error ?.

Tags: cygwin

I have installed cygwin packages on windows 7 32bit. And installing hadoop in CYGWIN i encountered command not found error for net start sshd command. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496079/bash-ssh-host-config-command-not-found) might work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Before be able to start the sshd cygwin service you need :

1) install the package openssh with cygwin setup.
After installation you can verify it with

```
 $ cygcheck -c openssh
    Cygwin Package Information
    Package              Version        Status
    openssh              7.2p2-1        OK
```

2) configure the sshd server and likely the user default
using the dedicate config scripts:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-host-config
/usr/bin/ssh-user-config
```

3) start the service with

```
cygrunsrv -S sshd
```

Please note that `net start sshd` is the Windows method to start a service and it can fail if the system32 directory is not in the PATH used by your cygwin

Comment: i have tried out that $ cygcheck -c openssh And /usr/bin/ssh-host-config
/usr/bin/ssh-user-config Commands but still the command not found error occurs ?... $ cygcheck -c openssh
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
openssh              7.2p2-1        OK                                                           $ net start sshd
-bash: net: command not found         $ ssh localhost                                                                 ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
$ explorer
-bash: explorer: command not found

Comment: What is the output of  `cygrunsrv -L` ? If ssh is not reported what is the result of `/usr/bin/ssh-host-config` ? . If it is reported what is the output of `cygrunsrv -S sshd`  ?

Comment: I my case I found ``ssdh.exe`` located in ``c:\Tools\cygwin64\usr\sbin\`` so I have to add that in to ``path`` variable manually.

Answer (score 0):

Santhoshi@Nagarajan-PC ~
$ cygcheck -c openssh
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
openssh              7.2p2-1        OK

Santhoshi@Nagarajan-PC ~
$ ssh-host-config

*** Info: Generating missing SSH host keys**
 Query: Overwrite existing /etc/ssh_config file? (yes/no) yes
 **Info: Creating default /etc/ssh_config file
*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/sshd_config file? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Creating default /etc/sshd_config file

*** Info: StrictModes is set to 'yes' by default.**
 Info: This is the recommended setting, but it requires that the POSIX
 **Info: permissions of the user's home directory, the user's .ssh**
 Info: directory, and the user's ssh key files are tight so that
 **Info: only the user has write permissions.**
 Info: On the other hand, StrictModes don't work well with default
 **Info: Windows permissions of a home directory mounted with the**
 Info: 'noacl' option, and they don't work at all if the home
 **Info: directory is on a FAT or FAT32 partition.
*** Query: Should StrictModes be used? (yes/no) no

*** Info: Privilege separation is set to 'sandbox' by default since**
 Info: OpenSSH 6.1.  This is unsupported by Cygwin and has to be set
 **Info: to 'yes' or 'no'.**
 Info: However, using privilege separation requires a non-privileged account
 **Info: called 'sshd'.**
 Info: For more info on privilege separation read /usr/share/doc/openssh/README.privsep.
 **Query: Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no) no
*** Info: Updating /etc/sshd_config file

*** Info: Sshd service is already installed.

*** Info: Host configuration finished. Have fun!

Santhoshi@Nagarajan-PC ~
$ net start sshd
-bash: net: command not found

Santhoshi@Nagarajan-PC ~
$ explorer
-bash: explorer: command not found

Santhoshi@Nagarajan-PC ~
$ ssh localhost                                                                 ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Comment: This is not an answer. You should have put this info in your question. `net: command not found` means that net is not in your path. Use `cygrunsrv -S sshd` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `sshd` command is not necessarily in your `PATH`.

Try:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd
```